# Springboot greater 3.0 and Spring-Security greater 6.0.0 having CORS error while implementing SecurityFilterChain

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have implemented rest apis using springboot 3.1.0 and spring-security 6.0.8. APIs are returning result using postman but throwing CORS error in browser. Whereas I have done lot many changes in

Any help will be appreciated:-

```
@Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:8080/", "http://localhost:4200/", "http://localhost:5174/", "custom url pointing to server"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_CHARSET, HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS,
                HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS,
                HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS,
                HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD, HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,
                HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_RANGES, HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_MAX_AGE,
                HttpHeaders.ALLOW, HttpHeaders.CONNECTION, HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING,
                HttpHeaders.REFERER, HttpHeaders.ORIGIN, HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, "X-Requested-With", HttpHeaders.ACCEPT));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of(HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name(), HttpMethod.GET.name(), HttpMethod.POST.name(), HttpMethod.PUT.name(),
                HttpMethod.PATCH.name(), HttpMethod.DELETE.name()));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param http
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
                .headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
                .cors().disable()
                //.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
               // .and()
                // weather controller has NOT been purposly defined below
                // Below order matters
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .requestMatchers(AUTH_PROTECTEDLIST).authenticated())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/admin/verifyAdmin").hasAuthority("verifyAdminPermission")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/vendor/vendorDshBrdCntApp").hasAuthority("viewOrgDetailPermission")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()) // anyRequest can be used only once
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .sessionManagement((session) -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .addFilterBefore(new CustomRequestHeaderTokenFilter(iTokenVerifier, authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);    // OK ---
        return http.build();
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

And CUSTOM FILTER :-

```
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {


        Enumeration<String> headerToken = request.getHeaders(AUTH_HEADER_NAME);

        if (headerToken == null) {
            this.logger.trace("No Authorization header found!");

            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
            authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
//            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://portal.dev.flex-nonprod.optum.com");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range");
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);

        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

I have tried lot many solution like :-

https://gist.github.com/zachowdhury/aa7aa4bba469e199ed36458a24c33a96

But nothing is working after making any changes in either corsConfiguration or Filter, getting CORS error always

Comment: Your question is confusing me. What are you trying? Looks like you are mixing both CORS configuration/support in Spring Boot, with a custom Cors Filter and the regular support in Spring MVC. I have no clue what you are trying to do, first pick 1 solution and use that don't throw all of them together as that is troubel waiting to happen.